# Facebook Pixel - How to add people to the Facebook Pixel programmatically

Tags: facebook, facebook-pixel

We're currently trying to [Add People to a Facebook Pixel](https://www.facebook.com/business/help/279059996069252) by code instead of manually doing it. We were checking their API and it seems there's a way to [create a Pixel](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/audiences/guides/website-custom-audiences#createpixel), but we have yet to find out a way to add people into this pixel. The only thing that looks like sending a user param is [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ads-pixel/#Creating), however, I don't think we want to create an event for an external user...

Is it even possible to add people to the pixel with the current Facebook API? If so, what's the correct approach to deal with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were able to solve this issue. We just needed to include the `pixelId` and `assigned_users` as shown in the following POST request:

```
POST REQUEST
{FB_API_PATH}/{pixelId}/assigned_users?access_token={FB_ACCESS_TOKEN}&business={FB_BUSINESS_MANAGER_ID}

BODY
{
  "user": "{fbUserId}",
  "tasks": ["ANALYZE", "EDIT", "UPLOAD", "ADVERTISE", "AA_ANALYZE"]
}
```